# spring cron scheduled not running in the second day

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduler, scheduling

I was tried to implement scheduler with setting for every day. Then I build to a jar file and running with "java -jar". I trying on my computer to still alive until 2 days for test it. Yesterday it's works. But when I look today is not running. Refer from this https://riptutorial.com/spring/example/21209/cron-expression.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Scheduler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 18 * * ?")
    public void currentTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        log.info("Current Time      = {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        log.info("Excel File has been generated");
    }

}
```

[this log on the second day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZzm.png)

Comment: It's not recommended to post screenshots of the code, better add code snippet.

Comment: Do you have some other scheduled tasks running as well? Since @Scheduled runs by default on single thread, it may be possible that other task is not allowing this task to run.

Comment: Hi @Najib did you find an answer for this issue

Answer (score 3):

- I saw your images and I tested your cron expression [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html#) and It gives an error i.e
  `Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.`
- **Right Cron Expression**
  `0 30 16 * * ?`
- It specify that Your job is trigger 16:30: 00 pm every day.
- Also as per `@Jason's` answer you also have to use `@EnableScheduling` to your configuration `class`.

**Reference:**  [Cron Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm)

Comment: Yes, I have also @EnableScheduling in main class SpringBoot. But the main problem is my scheduler not running in second day. In first day the scheduler is running well without problem.

Comment: @Najib Kindly try with my suggested cron expression and also use the `SimpleDateFormat()` inside the method. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Najib, it seems like this should be straightforward, so I was testing it locally and I was having a difficult time getting an instance time at a specific hour to run, but I figured out why I had a problem. Can I ask, are you calculating your cron time in UTC? I wasn't and it was throwing off my result.

**Working example**

```java
package com.brand.server.v1;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class Scheduler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);

    static {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        LOG.info("The current time is: {}", sdf.format(new Date()));
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 30 22 * * ?")
    public void currentTimeDifferentName() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        LOG.info("Current time = {}", sdf.format(new Date()));
        LOG.info("File has been generated");
    }


    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */15 * * * ?")
    public void heartbeat() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        LOG.info("Heartbeat = {}", sdf.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**Log snippet from 20:00 Mountain Standard Time**

```
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:24:48.496  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:24:48.499  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.brand.server.v1.ServerApplication    : Started ServerApplication in 5.181 seconds (JVM running for 5.827)
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:30:00.001  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 22:30:00
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Current time = 22:30:00
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : File has been generated
server_1     | 2020-05-14 22:45:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 22:45:00
server_1     | 2020-05-14 23:00:00.001  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 23:00:00
server_1     | 2020-05-14 23:15:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 23:15:00
...
server_1     | 2020-05-15 22:15:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 22:15:00
server_1     | 2020-05-15 22:30:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Heartbeat = 22:30:00
server_1     | 2020-05-15 22:30:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : Current time = 22:30:00
server_1     | 2020-05-15 22:30:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.brand.server.v1.Scheduler            : File has been generated
```

Comment: It's still running in second days?

Comment: I haven't been able to leave it up that long. Maybe this weekend I'll give it a 48 hours test. I typically try to keep my electronics powered off for conservation. Did you consider that you missed the log because of the cron being in epoch time?

Comment: My concern on the second day. So I just make sure it's running well on the second day. You can see my log on the second day. The scheduler not working properly.

Comment: I ran a multi-day test and the scheduler fired at the correct time each day.